# Nuxt, Webpack Optimization for SEO performance: "chunks: initial" faster then "chunks: all" or "chunks: async"

Tags: performance, webpack, optimization, nuxt.js, seo

I'm working on SEO optimization of my site focusing on mobile devices.

My setup: Nuxt v2 with SSR mode for page I'm testing, NestJS backend, MongoDB.

I'm measuring site performance with https://pagespeed.web.dev/ (I know that results are not precise, it can be different from time to time, etc.). For each test I'm running like 15-20 tests in 30 minutes, so each run is unique and it's definitely evaluated each time.

And I'm looking into the `Performance` section (FCP, Speed Index, LCP)

And I've noticed a few strange things:

1. When I have a config like that (`nuxt.config.js`):

> ```
> optimization: {
>   minimize: true,
>   splitChunks: {
>     chunks: 'all',
>     cacheGroups: {
>       vendor: {
>         name: 'node_vendors',
>         test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
>       },
>     },
>   },
> }
> ```

I can see (`yarn nuxt build --analyze`) that I have 1.62 MB total output bundles. All right, seems good.

[image: Screen here]

**When I'm testing it with https://pagespeed.web.dev/ for mobiles I have in average something near 50 performance score constantly. And my LCP is near 3 seconds all the time.**

2. When I have a config like that (`nuxt.config.js`):

> ```
> optimization: {
>   minimize: true,
>   splitChunks: {
>     chunks: 'initial',
>     cacheGroups: {
>       vendor: {
>         name: 'node_vendors',
>         test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
>       },
>     },
>   },
> }
> ```

Then I have almost 4.35 MB total output bundles. Twice as much, right?

[image: Screen here]

**In that case for mobiles I have in average near 70 performance score. LCP is near 1.5-1.8 seconds all the time.**

And here is my question - why it's happening and what is the logic behind it?

It seems really counter intuitive. Bundle size x2.5 bigger, but performance score is much much better when `chunks: 'initial'`.

Any thoughts?

I've tried all the possible `chunks` options and came to that result.

I was expecting that our goal is to have as small bundle size as possible to improve performance scores. But in reality it doesn't work that intuitive way.

Comment: any news on this? Did you end up using 'initial' or did you find something different? I am facing a similar issue

Comment: @Callan I just chose the higher performing option according to pagespeed

Answer (score 1):

During working on my project I was confused with that as well until I started to analyse the chunks a bit closer. As you can see in your example, you have i.e. katex.js file added into multiple chunks. That means overall size of the package will increase as it will have the same files added multiple times. From my understanding this is because of some modules dependencies. But it helps for the performance as only necessary chunks can be server to the browser, which reduce the overal size on page load as only few chunks might be loaded for  specific page. You could also specify max chunk size and create many many more chunks but apparently it's not too good either so you need to find some good balance for the chunk size. I am not an expert so this is just my observation when I was experimenting with split chunks option and cache groups.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).